# Как сверстать данную секцию?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сверстать, данную секцию?
 Мне в голову приходят только варианты: сделать `div.section_right and div.section_left` - один блок с контентом - другой пустой и `border` одного `div` использовать, как белую линию. Или же сделать три `div` блока (один отдельно для линии). Но боюсь, что во всех вариантах, при адаптиве будет что-попало. В общем подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сверстать, или как бы сверстали его Вы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про адаптив у вас мысли правильные. В итоге всё равно эти блоки придётся делать на всю ширину один под другим с сохранением порядка. Поэтому лучше обойтись без лишних обёрток.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  background-color:#555;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
}
.container:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  height:100%;
  border-left:1px solid;
}
.element{
  width:calc(50% - 10px);
  height:100px;
  background-color:#cda;
  position:relative;
}
.element:nth-child(2n){
  margin-left:auto;
}
.element:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:#555;
  border:2px solid;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 5px);
  right: -18px;
}
.element:nth-child(2n):before{
  right:auto;
  left:-17px;
}
.element:nth-child(3):before{
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  right:-22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал использовать Dynamic Animated Timeline Slider With jQuery - Roadmap или что-то похожее. Удобное решение для подобных задач.